# How to add dynamic value to URLFOR after path

Tags: apex, standardcontroller, visuaforce, variable

I have an apex repeat which I want to use to add an dynamic id at the end of the URLFOR but get an syntax error what is wrong with my annotation

See:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!idsContentdocument}" var="file">
    <a href="{!URLFOR('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/'+{!file.ContentDocumentId})}" target="_blank"> Click here </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    {!file.ContentDocument.title} 
    <br/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I think it may be the `!` in `{!file.ContentDocumentID}`. Try removing that and see if that works. As -- `{!URLFOR('.....' + file.ContentDocumentId)}`

Comment: @JayantDas So simple but it was the solution. Thx please refer as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rolling up from comments.

You don't need to refer `!` in `{!file.ContentDocumentID}`. Removing that should work.

```
<a href="{!URLFOR('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/' + file.ContentDocumentId)} ..>
```

Comment: Could you please explain on what the 5 dots mean here?

Comment: @Raul those were just a representation of what is already in there. Let me update it with existing values as in the question to make sure there's no confusion.